# How to run UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_PARALLEL from a procedure?

Tags: oracle, object, package, recompile

I have a simple question: Is it possible to run UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_PARALLEL from a procedure?
I have a Package with a procedure which should recompile all invalid objects. It looks like this:

```
    PROCEDURE Compile ()
    IS
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('BEGIN SYS.UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_PARALLEL(4,); END;');
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);

    END;
```

However, I always get the Error **PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_PARALLEL' must be declared**
I am logged in as sys/sysdba user. That's not the problem.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Thanks!

Comment: From the documentation - "This package must be run using SQL*PLUS."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it works if the procedure is owned by SYS and you grant EXECUTE privilege to another user (doc says "You must be connected AS SYSDBA to run this script").

```
SQL> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> show user;
USER is "SYS"
SQL> --
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Compile
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4   SYS.UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_PARALLEL(4);
  5  END;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> --
SQL> grant execute on compile to c##test;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> --
SQL> connect c##test/c##test
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "C##TEST"
SQL> --
SQL> drop table t purge;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table t(x int);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p
  2  is
  3  v int;
  4  begin
  5   select x into v from t;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> --
SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL> --
SQL> drop table t;

Table dropped.

SQL> --
SQL> select object_name, object_type, status
  2  from user_objects
  3  where object_name='P';

OBJECT_NAM OBJECT_TYP STATUS
---------- ---------- ----------
P      PROCEDURE  INVALID

SQL> --
SQL> create table t(x int);

Table created.

SQL> --
SQL> select object_name, object_type, status
  2  from user_objects
  3  where object_name='P';

OBJECT_NAM OBJECT_TYP STATUS
---------- ---------- ----------
P      PROCEDURE  INVALID

SQL> --
SQL> exec sys.compile;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> --
SQL> select object_name, object_type, status
  2  from user_objects
  3  where object_name='P';

OBJECT_NAM OBJECT_TYP STATUS
---------- ---------- ----------
P      PROCEDURE  VALID

SQL> --
```

These kind of procedures should be run only by SYS (like utlrp.sql) - so this is for DBA only - as documented to avoid unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in a stored procedure:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> --
SQL> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL> show user;
USER is "SYS"
SQL> --
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Compile
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4   UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_PARALLEL(4);
  5   EXCEPTION
  6     WHEN OTHERS
  7     THEN
  8     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
  9  END;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> --
SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL> --
SQL> set timing on
SQL> exec compile;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.31
SQL> --
SQL> exit
```

Comment: Its not working for me. Just the same Error. But maybe its due to Procedure which is inside a package. Sorry, I forgot to say this... THe procedure itself is inside a package which is not in the SYS Schema, but in ontehr one. But I am connected as sys/sysdba

Comment: So, i thing i have found the Reason for this problem. I need to grant the rights to the other Schema which contains the Package  to execute this sys.Utl_recomp.

GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.UTL_RECOMP TO **YOUR_SCHEMA**

Comment: I just checked that this is not really working. I have no errors but id does nothing. If I just put **SYS.UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_PARALLEL(4)** and execute this proceure, nothing happens. Objects are not compiled.

Any other ideas or approaches?